# Mockito Disregard Parameters

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Is there a way to get a mocked class to return some object no matter what arguments the function is called with?

For example, if one of my parameters' types did not have the .equals() method properly implemented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
when(mock.someMethod(any()).thenReturn(yourValue);
```

The *any()* matcher basically says you can have any value or a null. Check out the [documentation](http://mockito.org/) at mockito, especially the section on Argument Matchers.

Answer (score 3):

There are also generics i.e.

```
when(mock.someMethod(Matchers.<String>any(), Matchers.<Interval>any(), Matchers.Integer>any())).thenReturn(yourValue);
```